# query malformed, no start_object after query name in simple query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I run this query in Kibana that connected to Elastic Search

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "date": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And got error:
`query malformed, no start_object after query name`

Why is that?

Comment: The query you gave in the question is working fine. Can you please check the query which you posted above?

Comment: @ESCoder I edit the post , I put this query in Kibana

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the query object

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "date": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```